# get distinct objects from an array based on a subset of keys

Tags: javascript

I've written some code that is yielding the desired results but it seems verbose.  The code gets the distinct objects from an array of objects when looking at only a subset of the keys.  Is there a more concise way to write the code to get the same output?

```js
const source = [
    {"id":"1","department":"grocery","storeLocation":"downtown","shelf":"21","slot":"A12","item":"celery"},
    {"id":"2","department":"hardware","storeLocation":"mall","shelf":"57","slot":"452","item":"flashlights"},
    {"id":"3","department":"grocery","storeLocation":"downtown","shelf":"21","slot":"B17","item":"cabbage"},
    {"id":"4","department":"grocery","storeLocation":"downtown","shelf":"21","slot":"D28","item":"lettuce"},
    {"id":"5","department":"hardware","storeLocation":"mall","shelf":"57","slot":"493","item":"duct tape"}
];

const distinctCombinations = {};
source.forEach(o => {
    distinctCombinations[o.storeLocation] = { storeLocation: o.storeLocation, department: o.department, shelf: o.shelf }
});

const result = Object.values(distinctCombinations);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I came up with:

```js
const source = [
    {"id":"1","department":"grocery","storeLocation":"downtown","shelf":"21","slot":"A12","item":"celery"},
    {"id":"2","department":"hardware","storeLocation":"mall","shelf":"57","slot":"452","item":"flashlights"},
    {"id":"3","department":"grocery","storeLocation":"downtown","shelf":"21","slot":"B17","item":"cabbage"},
    {"id":"4","department":"grocery","storeLocation":"downtown","shelf":"21","slot":"D28","item":"lettuce"},
    {"id":"5","department":"hardware","storeLocation":"mall","shelf":"57","slot":"493","item":"duct tape"}
];

const distinctCombinations = [...new Set(source.map(o => JSON.stringify(o, ['storeLocation', 'department', 'shelf'])))].map(o => JSON.parse(o));

console.log(distinctCombinations);
```